# Browser extension - run web worker on demand after button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, web-worker, browser-extension

I'm working on a browser extension that will act like a download manager. The user will have the ability to add multiple files in a queue, I want to give the ability to start at least two download simultaneusly. To implement this I'm thinking to use web workers but I have some doubt about it. Mainly I want to run the web worker only when the user click on the download button of each file and to achive this I'm not sure if implement the js code into the `background.js` file that run as persistent, or if it will be better to call it from the popup js code. The worker will also use the `importScripts()` because I need an external library to do the downloads, about this point, if I understand well, after the import the script content will be available to the worker and every spawned child right? What will be the best approach to achive my scope?

Comment: If the downloads happen automatically in the browser when an a tag with a download attribute is clicked (either by script or otherwise) why need workers? The real problem is to detect when a file completely download to know when to start the next download

Comment: @bluejayke the library who manage the download is an m3u8 parser. It will download and join video segments, after this operation the browser save window will be displayed and internally a `finished` event is fired, so it's not a big problem to know when a download end. The sidenote is that the library will not start the download automatically but require to be instructed to do it. I'm thinking to a worker to have multiple instances of the library running in bg and have multiple downloads simultaneusly